# java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server, With apache FTPClient

Tags: java, apache, sockets, ftp

I am trying to connect to FTP Server using Apache FTPCleint in java web start aplication.
Below is the code i am using.

```
ftpInstance = new FTPClient();

ftpInstance.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);

ftpInstance.connect(<HostName>);
int rpyCode = ftpInstance.getReplyCode();

if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(rpyCode)){
    throw new Exception("Connection Rejected with reply code " + rpyCode + ". - " + <Hostname>);
}
```

Problem is at line  `ftpInstance.connect(<HostName>)`. An exception is been thrown Please look at the stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
at com.newgen.backend.Operation.call(Operation.java:91)
at filetransfermanager.FileTransferManagerView$1.windowOpened(FileTransferManagerView.java:48)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowOpened(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:192)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:285)
at com.newgen.ftp.FTPInstance.getInstance(FTPInstance.java:38)
at com.newgen.backend.Transport.<init>(Transport.java:58)
at com.newgen.backend.Operation.call(Operation.java:81)
... 27 more
```

Above code is working fine in normal project but not in java web start.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have configured SOCKS proxy settings that point to something that isn't a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: I have tried removing all the proxy settings from IE and java plugin network settings but no luck. same thing is working as an applet in the browser but problem exist only in case of java web start.

Comment: @Kyle That is exactly what this entire answer already provides.